# Error a redireccionar pagina a partir de un elemento a

Tags: jquery, html5

Estoy teniendo problema con re direccionamiento a otra pagina a partir de un bloque de código en `html` que se agrega con el método `append()` de `jquery`. Dentro del bloque tengo un elemento `a` el cual asigno una url a partir de atributo `href`, pero no estaría logrando el re direccionamiento. También intente con el atributo `onclick="window.open('url')"`

Adjunto el código

```js
$(document).on('click', '#buttonCalcular', function(event) {
  var cantEstudios = 0;
  var total = 0;
  bloque = '
    <div class="hijo col-md-10" role="alert" style="background-color: #e2e3e5; border-radius: 1px;">
      <h5 class="text-center">
        <strong>Resumen - Estudios realizado con obras sociales</strong>
      </h5><br>
      <div class="text-center"><br>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="http://google.com">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>Ver Detalles
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>';
  $('#facturacion').append(bloque);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="textFechaInicio" class="control-label text-muted">Seleccionar periodo de facturación</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
        <button id="buttonCalcular" type="button" name="buscar" class="btn btn-success btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-search" onclick="" style="top: 0px;"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p class="text-muted" style="margin-left: 10px;">Detalles de facturación</p>
      <hr/>
      <div id="facturacion">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué pasa cuando haces clic?

Comment: Cambia el enlace de google que tienes en el `href`, prueba por ejemplo con `https://es.stackoverflow.com` . Lo acabo de probar y funciona.

Comment: Si probé con el link que comentas, pero no funciona por ejemplo con la url de google me arroja el siguiente error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Comment: Posiblemente se deba a que la construcción del bloque está fallando. Recién nos indicas qué error se muestra. El error se muestra en la consola del navegador? SI es así, es posible que debas cambiar la forma en la que construyes el fragmento del DOM, pues parecería que hay conflictos entre las comillas dobles y simples.

Answer (score 0):

La variable `bloque` por que no la creas utilizando [plantillas de cadena de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) de esta forma podras colocar todo el html completo. Si decides utilizar la comilla simple o doble comillas entonces deberas crear varias cadenas concatenandola con el simbolo de `+`.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#buttonCalcular', function(event) {
  var cantEstudios = 0;
  var total = 0;
  bloque = `
    <div class="hijo col-md-10" role="alert" style="background-color: #e2e3e5; border-radius: 1px;">
      <h5 class="text-center">
        <strong>Resumen - Estudios realizado con obras sociales</strong>
      </h5><br>
      <div class="text-center"><br>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="http://google.com">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>Ver Detalles
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>`;
  $('#facturacion').append(bloque);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="textFechaInicio" class="control-label text-muted">Seleccionar periodo de facturación</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
        <button id="buttonCalcular" type="button" name="buscar" class="btn btn-success btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-search" onclick="" style="top: 0px;"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p class="text-muted" style="margin-left: 10px;">Detalles de facturación</p>
      <hr/>
      <div id="facturacion">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Si no deceas utilizar las plantillas de cadenas, entonce tu javascript quedaria:

```
$(document).on('click', '#buttonCalcular', function(event) {
  var cantEstudios = 0;
  var total = 0;
  bloque = 
    '<div class="hijo col-md-10" role="alert" style="background-color: #e2e3e5; border-radius: 1px;">' +
    '  <h5 class="text-center">' +
    '    <strong>Resumen - Estudios realizado con obras sociales</strong>' +
    '  </h5><br>' +
    '  <div class="text-center"><br>' +
    '    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="http://google.com">' +
    '      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>Ver Detalles' +
    '    </a>' +
    '  </div>' +
    '</div>';
  $('#facturacion').append(bloque);
});
```

> Nota: debes probar el ejemplo fuera de los snippet de stackoverflow, de lo contrario bloqueara el redireccionamiento.

Te recomiendo leer las especificaciones y compatibilidad de las plantillas de cadena. [Especificaciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings#Especificaciones) y [Compatibilidad de navegadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings#Compatibilidad_de_navegadores)